# How to declare a shared pointer in member initialization list

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I'm trying to add a shared pointer to my initialization list. This pointer has already been declared in my header file. Once i add it to the list, the compiler errors out with `error: no matching function for call to std::shared_ptr<memory::Mmu>::shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<Cartridge>&)`

header file:

```
class Gameboy {
    public:
        Gameboy(std::vector<uint8_t>);
        void run();
    private:
        void tick();
        std::shared_ptr<Cartridge> cartridge;
        std::shared_ptr<memory::Mmu> mmu;
};
```

c file:

```
Gameboy::Gameboy(std::vector<uint8_t> cartridgeData)
    : cartridge(getCartridge(std::move(cartridgeData))),
      mmu(cartridge)
    {

    }
```

mmu.h

```
namespace memory {
    class Mmu {
        public:
            std::shared_ptr<Cartridge> cartridge;
            Mmu(std::shared_ptr<Cartridge>&);

        private:
            bool bootRomActive() const;
    };
}
```

I expect it to call the mmu constructor which takes `std::shared_ptr<Cartridge>&` as first param.

Comment: You couldn't initialize a raw pointer like that either. Have you considered [make_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) or similar?

Comment: Oh, also, correct code and the full error please. I'm just assuming that the error is the obvious one, but you haven't shown it, and as Jarod42 pointed out, your code isn't consistent.

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_ptr<T>` does not have a constructor that accepts a `std::shared_ptr<Y>` when `Y` does not derive from `T`.

Assuming your `Cartridge` does not derive from `memory::Mmu` (you did not show the declaration of `Cartridge`), then you cannot construct a `std::shared_ptr<memory::Mmu>` directly from a `std::shared_ptr<Cartridge>`.  Hence the error message.

If you need to construct a new `memory::Mm` that references a `Cartridge`, then in the `Gameboy` member initialization list, change this:

```
mmu(cartridge)
```

To either:

```
mmu(new memory::Mm(cartridge))
```

Or:

```
mmu(std::make_shared<memory::Mm>(cartridge))
```